# How to force directories beeing created for my link

Tags: bash, ln

I have a large file with links beeing created.

f.e.

```
    ln -s ../AAA2/myfile.txt ../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mylink.ln
```

unfortunately the destination directory structure is not created yet.
Is there a way to force the directories (here dirX ) beeing created before the link is created?

Thanks

Comment: @PesaThe thanks, can you explain the "$_ in the last part? Is this a variable?

Comment: Oh I made a mistake, I take it back, sorry.

Comment: @PesaThe Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not `ln`'s job to create directories; that's `mkdir`'s job.

```
dest=../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mylink.ln
mkdir -p "${dest%/*}"
ln -s ../AAA2/myfile.txt "$dest"
```

Comment: thanks, so I have to make 3 lines for one link. As the dest dirs are not always the same. Do I understand it correctly? Thanks

Comment: @WalterSchrabmair You can create a function using this code.

Comment: No, you have to use three lines to create multiple directories and one link. `../dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/mylink.ln` is not a link; it's a path. Only `mylink.ln` is the link created by `ln`; everything else is a set of directories that tell you where `mylink.ln` is. It would be even *more* lines if the `-p` option didn't exist; you'd have to write `mkdir ../dir1; mkdir ../dir1/dir2; mkdir ../dir1/dir2/dir3; ...`.